# Regex with backreference won't match in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to match 4 equal characters in C++.

These are supposed to match = `KQQQQ, ZZZZQ`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
std::string mano_to_reg = "KQQQQ";
std::regex pokar("(.)\1{3}");
std::smatch match;

std::cout << "match = " << std::regex_match(mano_to_reg, match, pokar) << "\n";
```

But It won't match.

I've also tried `std::regex_search` , but it won't match either.

I've tried using basic and extend syntax

I've also tried changing my pattern to `"(.)\1{4}"` , `"((.)\1{3})"` and every other combination of these.

I've tried matching other patterns to other strings and most of them work. It seems the problem is the backreference, but I've looked everywhere and I can't find why it wont match.

I'm using clang++ 7.0.2 on OS X 10.11.3 with -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ flags.

I've also tried g++ 5.3.0 with -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 flags.

Comment: You should start with escaping the ``\`` character. You probably mean `"(.)\\1{3}"`.

Comment: That would match "\", what I'm trying to do is match the previous capture group {3} times to it would match 4 times the same character.

Comment: No, it wouldn't match `"\"` (that would be `"\\\\"`, which is the regex ``\\``). [You need to escape backslashes in string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). The regex `(.)\1{3}` is correct, but in order to write that in a string literal you need to escape ``\``, so it's `"(.)\\1{3}"`.

Comment: I tried `"(.)\\1{3}"` but it won't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two problems:

1. You need to [escape `\`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). The regex `(.)\1{3}` is correct, but in order to store that in a string literal, you need to escape it so it's `"(.)\\1{3}"`.
2. You probably want [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) instead of [`std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). The string `"KQQQQ"` does not match the regex `(.)\1{3}`, but the substring `"QQQQ"` does.

The following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string mano_to_reg = "KQQQQ";
    std::regex pokar("(.)\\1{3}");
    std::smatch match;

    std::cout << "match  = " << std::regex_match(mano_to_reg, match, pokar) << "\n";
    std::cout << "search = " << std::regex_search(mano_to_reg, match, pokar) << "\n";
}
```

[outputs:](http://ideone.com/Mo4NKk)

```
match  = 0
search = 1
```

Comment: That did, thank you so much !, I've been struggling with this for hours.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Thanks for posting a well-worded question with clear code that I (and others) could read and use; it's nice to see a new user post a great first question.

Comment: In this case “you’ve got two problems” is funny because it is true.